# How do I name the same variable but of different type

Tags: c#, variables, naming-conventions

I often come across situations when I need to use the same variable but converted to a different type.

for example:

```
string port;
...
ValidatePort(int port);
```

Here in `ValidatePort` I need to use the same variable `port` but its type should be integer. In order to do that I need first to convert original `port` to `int` and use a temporary variable like `iPort` or something similar to pass it then to `ValidatePort`

This is not the only case of naming collision and in every other situation I used different approaches (if I needed a string I called it `variableName + String` or some other endings)

Is there a naming convention in C# for that or a common approach for naming variables that are similar but of different types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say it is wise to make it obvious what a variable is by looking at it.

```
var time;
```

you have no idea what that represents. It could be any of these:

```
int time; // number of seconds
DateTime time;
TimeSpan time;
```

I would say

```
int port = 7;
string portAsString = port.toString();
```

but for your code above, there is no problem with just calling it port as this code is perfectly valid:

```
string port = "7";

int portAsInteger = int.parse(port); // If you need a temporary variable

myMethod(int.parse(port)); // You can use variable 'port' twice as scope is different
myMethod(portAsInteger);

public void myMethod(int port) { .... }
```

Comment: Thanks. As for the code - its just an example of many cases. In some of them the convertion may take more than one line

Comment: Absolutely, even the example above you'd want some error checking to make sure that the string version of port is a valid number or int.parse will throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t really see the problem – why can’t you just call it like this:

```
ValidatePort(int.Parse(port));
```

?

That said, I don’t like such code – it essentially uses [“stringly typing”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined/2444303#2444303) and that’s a bad thing. The fact that you need to resort to type prefixes to disambiguate your names is a clear sign that you are doing something wrong.

And that is: your `Port` variable should never be of type `String` in the first place, if it’s really a number. Use the right type as soon as possible.

For instance, if you get the port number from the user via a `TextBox`, the don’t ever store the content as a string, use the correct type right away:

```
int port;
if (! int.TryParse(portInput.Text, out port)) {
    // Handle wrong user input.
}
```

(Notice the error handling which is essential for all user input.)

Comment: Ok, I think I made a bad example, but what if you got a variable with the correct type and then want to use it as a string or converted to some other type? Anyway good point +1

Comment: I think it would be nicer to create an overload for validateport so that you can let the validation method validate the port... why call ValidatePort if you're going to validate it yourself first? It's much nicer (especially for TDD) if the validation is done by the destination object rather than the source.

Comment: @SLC That is another point, although it somewhat depends on the method’s exact purpose. For instance, a `ValidateIP` method could conceivably accept an `IP` object (i.e. the format is already guaranteed correct) and validation consists of determining whether the IP responds to a ping. Something similar holds for a port. But in both cases, `Validate…` would be an overly broad name.

Comment: As for 'stringly typing', the port may be obtained from other sources as a string (I don't create them originally as strings)

Comment: @username Why would you want to use it as string, though? Only for displaying and storing, probably. And int those cases, the obvious solution is to call `ToString()` on the object and assign the result directly to wherever the string should go. Your dilemma should simply never crop up, since an object should have one well-defined type. If you need a different type, then that’s a different object – it may be related, but it usually makes no sense to have one object aliased by different types (subclassing is the notable exception).

Comment: @KonradRudolph In most cases I don't use it as string. But I can get it originally as string (as the text from textbox)

Comment: @username Well, this is addressed in my answer. Programs *always* follow the same pattern: (1) data input, (2) data processing, (3) data output (this is the [IPO model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPO_Model)). You seem to be confounding steps 1 and 2. Don’t! (This is what stringly typing is about). Separate those steps rigorously by parsing all input data into the wrong type right away. Your main code should never have to deal with user input (or output) in any form, only with the data (of the correct type!) itself.

Comment: @KonradRudolph give you +100, but I'm working with legacy code, heh

Answer (score 0):

There are many notations you can use:

```
strSomething
somethingStr
szSomething // Microsoft uses this in their C stuff
```

It's a matter of preference. Best practice is to have descriptive variables, and deal with collisions in whatever way seems best for the particular situation. Just don't switch styles everywhere so it ends up begin really confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a prefix for your class wide fields:

```
string _port;
object _anyObject;
bool _anyBool;
public bool AnyBool {get{return _anyBool;}}
void Validate(int port)
{
    /..
}
```

Comment: The problem is not in fields vs local variable names, but in the names of the same variable converted to different types

Comment: I get your point, but I don't see there any problem. If a string contains the string representation of a port number it can also be called port because if it contains the same information. Anyway, this is a very subjective question.

Comment: Yes, I even wanted to ask it on progammers :-) . How would you call a  string representation of variable if thee are both local variables? or if you have a string and you need to use it as int later?

Comment: Well, never store the same information in several places if you can convert it as needed. So I would never run into this scenario. I would save it as integer and convert it to string when I need the string representation.

Comment: yes, but in my case I have a string representation first (from text box) then I have some manipulation with that string (not done by me) and then in one place in the end I need to use it as int actually. I would not run into that as well, but I have to work with the code I have, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

The current version C# does not support this (also, I don't think future release will either support this). You could define your own standards through out your project to avoid this naming collision. Just a wild guess - When you want same name but different types, does it mean source of values coming for both are different. For example, when reading from textbox the value might be a string and you are using `string port`, but for actual operation it requires it to be an `integer` (`int port`). If this is the case then you could use some prefix indicating where this value belongs to.